# How to assign the host ip to a service that is running with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have several services specified inside a docker compose file that are communication with each other via links. Now I want one of these services to talk to the outside world and fetch some data from another server in the host network. But the docker service uses its internally assigned IP address which leads to the firewall of the host network blocking his requests. How can I tell this docker service to use the IP address of the host instead?

EDIT:
I got a step further, what I'm looking for is the [network_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) option with the value `host`. But the Problem is that `network_mode: "host" cannot be mixed with links.` So i guess i have to change the configuration of all the docker services to not use links. I will try how this works out.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a port like to that service

```
ports:
    8000:8000
```

The `8000` on the left is the host port and the `8000` on the right will be the IP port

Comment: Hi I, do have the required ports open so that other systems can talk to the service running inside docker. So incoming traffic is correctly forwarded to the docker service. The problem is that outgoing traffic should use the ip adress of the host and not that of the internal default network between the docker containers.